# How to create a list of expandable items

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Have to create a ListBox or similar control with expandable items for WP8 SL:

- Only one item can be expanded at the same time
- Animation should apply on expanding of the item
- Animation should apply on collapsing of the item
- Animation of a new selected item should start only after the collapsing animation of the previous item
- Collapsed area should have it's own MouseOver state (Highlighting)

I tried to use [Toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/) and [Bewise Phone Controls](http://bewisephonecontrols.codeplex.com/) for the expandable items. In first case the ExpanderView is holding a collection in second case it looked perfect for our case.

Now about the control that is going to represent the collection of expandable items on the screen. I tried to use ListBox but it's impossible to "unselect" an item if the selection mode is set to Single. Decided to go with ItemsControl.

Current problem is Animations, all examples that I found deal only with scaling and rotating, but I have to use slide down animation which will incrementally increase the size of the parent (to move down the other elements).

Maybe someone solved this kind of problem in the past and can share the experience with me.

Thank you.

P.S.: The code sample is quite long, however if needed I could post part of it.

Comment: Have you played with any of the `Accordion` controls yet?

Comment: What you mean by `Accordion` controls? Where can I find them? Are they a part of the SDK or third party library?

Comment: Is there not one that comes with the sdk like you'd find in wpf/SL, etc? If not, they're not tough to make, but it's not like a 10minute thing. Last one I had to make custom was XAML only and took a couple hours to make/test but it wasn't for WP.

Comment: WP is more limited than WPF, all the xamples that I found unfortunately can't be used on WP.

Comment: True that WP and WPF are different but similar in some things. However take it from a dude that's worked in every xaml schema under the sun, there's always a way, even in WP. So for example, you could make your own accordion in WP via a User Control that had an ItemsControl with some styled Radio's and ContentPresenters with some storyboards to meet your all your requirements including the animations and result in a nice accordion with not much hassle. I wish I had spare time to throw it together for ya but it would take like an hour I don't have this week sorry amigo.